# How to add a 4 headphone amplifier to an audio interface (High imp headphones)

Tags: mixing, headphones

What's the best way to put a headphone splitter (also known as an amplifier) (say the [PreSonus HP4 Discrete 4-Channel Headphone Amp](https://www.guitarcenter.com/PreSonus/HP4-Discrete-4-Channel-Headphone-Amp-1274034489530.gc)) out of an audio interface (say the [Universal Audio Volt 2](https://www.guitarcenter.com/Universal-Audio/Volt-2-USB-Audio-Interface.gc?pdptypeAheadSearchInput=ua%20volt%202&tNtt=volt%202&tAt=item&tAv=Universal%20Audio%20Volt%202%20USB%20Audio%20Interface)):

- Out of the headphone output.
- Or out of the monitor outputs.

Comment: This is really 3 different but related questions.  The first two can arguably be answered together as they are closely related, but the final one is pretty independent and should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The input on the HP4 appears to be a line input, so monitor output would be preferable unless you specifically need something that only the headphone output can do.